# "Dirty mudder" - in a collection of short stories

Tags: story-identification

Part of some anthology I read about 500 years ago. Story was about dirt track racing and which tires to use and seeding the clouds during the race to create mud.

Yeah - not a great description and probably not a great book but I'm interested in finding it again.

Comment: It might help if you could be a little more specific about how long ago you read it. Was it before or after 1950?

Comment: Also, if you could explain how this is science fiction or fantasy. Cloud seeding is a real-world technology.

Comment: @Richard Cloud seeding is a real-world technology **now**, but 500 years ago it would have been science fiction.

Comment: 500 years ago?  What's your secret?!

Comment: @Tritium21 - He feasts each night on unicorn blood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is "[Sam and the Dirty Mudder](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64076)" by Dean Ing, originally printed in Omni Magazine in December 1979.

> The Nippan stopped on the course; the  cloud pall loomed so dark now,
> still only  above the track, that the Nippan solar  panels couldn't
> catch any sun, rising or  otherwise. Big raindrops spattered on the
> track. Sam nodded, shifted his cigar, and  folded his arms. **Then I
> knew why Sam had  insisted I find the iodide crystals: Metered  into
> the Metro's exhaust, they were seeding  the vapor thrown up by all the
> others.** We  sat there in brilliant tropical sunshine and  watched as a
> tropical downpour descended all the way around the course.
>
> **The rain spelled instant disaster for most  of the competition. Their
> huge slick tires  were aquaplaning, and I saw Dall trying to  cobble
> up a snorkel in his pit.** Chatham  began to eat his tweed cap as the
> Blossom  floated past, the valiant Tasman steering  with one hand and
> bailing with the other. I  don't think Chatham wanted the money so
> much as he loathed losing to the Fokker.

You can read a full version online [here](http://archive.org/stream/omni-magazine-1979-12/OMNI_1979_12_djvu.txt).

Comment: For the record, 1979 isn't 500 years ago. It's 35 years ago.

Comment: It's about 250 in dog years. Maybe it's 500 hamster years?

Comment: It was part of a larger anthology. Maybe Omni put out a collection?

Comment: @ethrbunny - Internet Sci-fi Database says no, but it's not always exhaustive.

Comment: @ethrbunny - You may be confusing it for the sequel "Sam and the blizzard machine" which was collected in an omni anthology book the following year

Comment: Nah- I remember the reference to 'the fokker'.. but I would swear it was in some collection.. weird.